# AssemblyInfo.cs could not be opened - Unspecified Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I was working offline from TFS for a while in my solution.  I went back online (TFS) and when I tried to compile my solution I get this for a project I had added to this solution.

> AssemblyInfo.cs could not be opened - Unspecified Error

I checked and that file is there so not sure why it can't utilize/read it.

This is an ASP.NET Web Application and the project it's complaining about here is just a regular C# class library project.

Comment: Check your file in Windows Directory whether it is there or not and also check it if it is ready-only.

Comment: It's there and not read-only.  I had checked this before posting.

Comment: found it.  The project has a missing ref to its AssemblyInfo.cs

Answer (score 8):

I have had this happened to me in the past. This can be more of a Visual Studio problem more than anything else.

What this means is that the AssemblyInfo.cs file is either missing from the Properties folder in the project or there is a permissions issue. If there is a permissions issue, update the ACL (File > Properties > Security), close and re-open the project. If missing altogether, you just need to recreate it taking the following steps:

1. Within Visual Studio 2010, select **Tools** > **Create GUID**
2. Click **Copy** (or **New GUID** then **Copy**)
3. Click **Exit**
4. Expand the Properties folder in the Solution Explorer (<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to open)
5. Delete the AssemblyInfo.cs file shown with the exclaimation point
6. Double click on the Properties folder - this should open the Properties window
7. On the Application Tab, click the Application Information... button
8. Fill in the application information, paste the GUID you copied into the GUID field - when done click **OK**

**Source**: [Visual Studio 2010 Project Error AssemblyInfo.cs could not be opened](http://davidmsterling.blogspot.com/2011/05/visual-studio-2010-project-error.html)

Answer (score 2):

This error is usually thrown when the file doesn't exist locally (not on the server). Probably it was deleted by some mistake. If the file exists on the server you could obtain it from there and if it was deleted you could manually recreate and add it to the project.

Comment: the file's there locally in the bin of that project..

Comment: @CoffeeAddict, the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file should be located in a `Properties` subfolder. I don't know what it is doing in the `bin` folder but there is nothing that will look for it there. The bin folder is where you get the compiled output, not source code. Open your `.csproj` file with a text editor and you will see the reference there pointing to the Properties folder which is where the AssemblyInfo.cs file must be located.

Comment: correction it's in the properties folder.

Comment: @CoffeeAddict, are you able to open it from within Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes...able to open it up in VS.